# Unpack ... with missing arguments

Tags: r

I'm writing a function that accepts a variable number of arguments. Moreover, I would like the user to be able to leave some of these arguments as missing.

Consider just the task of turning the `...` into a list of arguments. Here is my first attempt:

```
f <- function(...) list(...)
```

This fails:

```
f(1,,2)
## Error in f(1, , 2) : argument is missing, with no default
```

I would like the result to be `list(1, NULL, 2)`. (I am not worried about distinguishing `f(1,,2)` from `f(1,NULL,2)`.)

Here is my second attempt:

```
g <- function(...)
{
    args <- match.call()
    miss <- vapply(args, identical, NA, quote(expr=))
    args[miss] <- list(NULL)
    args[[1L]] <- quote(list)
    eval.parent(args)
}
```

This works (sort of):

```
identical(g(1,,2), list(1, NULL, 2))
## [1] TRUE
```

However, it fails when forwarding dots:

```
gg <- function(...) g(...)
identical(gg(1,,2), list(1,NULL,2))
## [1] FALSE
```

Is there a way to achieve the same results as `g`, but in a way that allows forwarding dots and without using `match.call()`?

#### Edit: Issues with forwarding dots.

It's tempting to try the following:

```
h <- function(...)
{
    args <- substitute(list(...))
    miss <- vapply(args, identical, NA, quote(expr=))
    args[miss] <- list(NULL)
    eval.parent(args)
}
```

However, as @lionel points out, there will be issues if you try to forward `...` from another function:

```
hh <- function(...) h(letters, ...)
local({ a <- "foo"; h(a) })
## Error in eval(expr, p) : object 'a' not found
```

It seems like you either need the `expand.dots` functionality of `match.call`, or you need to use a quosure (from the *rlang* package).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the rlang package you have the option of ignoring empty arguments when capturing dots:

```
my_dots <- function(...) {
  rlang::dots_list(..., .ignore_empty = "all")
}

my_dots(1, , 2, )
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1
#>
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 2
```

If you really need to translate empty arguments as `NULL` there is no other choice than quoting the dots and evaluating them after you've converted the missing arguments. Now if you do that with `eval(substitute(alist(...))` you will get into trouble if you attempt to forward dots through several function calls. Base R provides no way of evaluating the quoted argument in their original environment.

Luckily it's easy to do by capturing the dots in quosures:

```
library("purrr")  # For convenient map_if()

my_dots <- function(...) {
  quos <- rlang::quos(..., .ignore_empty = "none")
  quos <- map_if(quos, rlang::quo_is_missing, function(x) NULL)
  map(quos, rlang::eval_tidy)
}

my_dots(1, , 2, )
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1
#>
#> [[2]]
#> NULL
#>
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 2
#>
#> [[4]]
#> NULL
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "you will get into trouble if you attempt to forward dots through several function calls"? Is this an issue for the answer I posted below?

Comment: I have replied to your answer with an example.

Comment: Note, however, that the quosure is much slower: `microbenchmark(g(1,,2), my_dots(1,,2))` shows that `my_dots` is about 140 times slower

Comment: Yes because the focus for rlang 0.1.0 was on functionality rather than performance. Dots capture is currently prototyped in R but will have a C implementation in the next version. Some overhead will remain though, in part because this evaluation API is focused on overscoping (evaluating with auxiliary data).

Comment: Just a note that the performance issues were fixed in rlang 0.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

@lionel gave me most of the information I needed, so I'm marking his answer as correct. The following seems to work:

```
h <- function(...)
{
    args <- substitute(list(...))
    miss <- vapply(args, identical, NA, quote(expr=))
    args[miss] <- list(NULL)
    eval.parent(args)
}
```

However, there might be issues with forwarding `...` from other functions.

Comment: consider another function g that calls your function h: `g <- function(...) h(letters, ...)`. The following will fail: `local({ a <- "foo"; g(a) })`. The confusing thing about it is that it will often seem to work if you're referring to objects from the global environment but it will start to fail as you use the function within a package and in other situations.