# Unpack dots provided from another function with missing named arguments

Tags: r, metaprogramming

Similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47316014/10782538). Given a function `f` with named arguments and a function `g` taking any number of arguments through `...`, how would one

```
f <- function(a)
  g(a = a)
g <- function(...)
  list(...)
f()
```

> Error in g(a = a) : argument "a" is missing, with no default

`rlang::dots_list` sadly did not provide an answer

```
f2 <- function(a)
  h(a = a)
h <- function(...)
  rlang::dots_list(..., .ignore_empty = 'all')
f2()
```

> Error in eval(expr, p) : argument "a" is missing, with no default

Edit:
To make the problem more clear, the function `g` may be called by a myriad of functions, and I'm looking for a way to handle the missing arguments within `g` and not `f`.

Answer (score 1):

You can forward ... to subfunctions to multiple depths without evaluating them as long as the subfunctions don't actually perform any evaluation themselves so you don't have to handle this in all functions that receive ... but at the point where it is evaluated you will need to deal with it somehow.

Assuming that f() should return a empty list handle the missing argument separately within g

```
f <- function(a) g(a = a)
g <- function(..., default = list()) if (missing(..1)) default else list(...)
f()
## [1] list()
```

or the following which checks each element of ... :

```
g <- function(..., default = list()) {
    L <- list()
    for(i in seq_len(...length())) {
      x <- try(eval.parent(list(...)[[i]]), silent = TRUE)
      L[[i]] <- if (inherits(x, "try-error")) default else x
    }
    names(L) <-  names(substitute(alist(...))[-1])
    L
}
f()
## $a
## list()
```

or within f:

```
f <- function(a) if (missing(a)) g() else g(a = a)
g <- function(...) list(...)
f()
## [1] list()
```

Comment: That is the most obvious answer, sadly what i'm looking for is a solution within `g`, not `f`. The setup behind the MVE is a function which may be called by a myriad of functions. And i'm looking for a way to avoid writing checks for every missing argument within the outer-calls.

Comment: Better, could be expanded using the suggested method from `help(dots)` eg. `lapply(seq_len(...length()), function(n)ifelse(missing(switch(n, ...)), NULL, switch(n, ...))`, removing NULL elements afterwards. Wonder if there's a simpler way. Should've thought of this solution. :-)

Comment: @Oliver, That is not a valid use of missing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be OK except you call `f()` without `a` argument at the end... try this:

```
f <- function(a)
  g(a = a)
g <- function(...)
  list(...)
f("example")
```

Or you have to provide a default value for `a`:

```
f <- function(a = "example")
  g(a = a)
g <- function(...)
  list(...)
f()
```

So the problem is not a missing argument in `g(...)`, but missing argument value in `f()` when calling `g(a = a)` without having `a`.

Comment: The point of the question is that the argument might be missing.

Comment: @Oliver Ah, sorry. Then you can check if `a` exists by `exists(a)`... and call `g()` withou arguments, if not.

Comment: That is also a possibility. Similar to Groeth's original answer however the point is that i want to be lazy, and avoid having to handle checking of missing arguments within every outer-function calling g, there there may be many. :-)

Comment: Oh, I see... sorry, this originally wasn't clear to me as this quite unusual... :-) Anyway, Groeth's solution seems to be getting very close to what you need!